# mongoid embedded document criteria not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

here's the models

```
class Scammer
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :email_used
  field :phone_used
  field :name_used
  field :first_logged, type: DateTime
  field :last_scam_attempt, type: DateTime
  field :checked, type: Integer, default: 0
  field :scams_count, type: Integer
  field :common_commodity
  field :status
  embeds_many :reports
  embeds_many :reporters
  embeds_many :requestors
end

class Report
    include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :scammer
    field :reported, type: DateTime
    field :posed_as
    field :encountered_through
    field :commodity
    field :details
    field :logged_by
end 

class Reporter
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :scammer
  field :reporter_ip
  field :captured, type: DateTime
end 

class Requestor
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :scammer
  field :requestor_ip
  field :captured, type: DateTime
end
```

And now here's the code I'm using to try to do something with these models

```
    # It's an email address, 
    if Scammer.where(email_used: @search_term).exists?
        if not Scammer.requestors.where(requestor_ip: request.remote_ip).exists?
        Scammer.requestors.create(requestor_ip: request.remote_ip, captured: DateTime.current()).save
                        end 
                        @return = Scammer.where(email_used: @search_term).to_json
                    else 
                        # No entry found. We should now add this to the database as a search
                        @newscammer = Scammer.new(email_used: @search_term, checked: 1, first_logged: DateTime.current(), status: "Seems Legit")
                        @newscammer.requestors.create(requestor_ip: request.remote_ip, captured: DateTime.current())
                        @newscammer.save
                        @return = "{ 'message' : 'Email added to database' }"
                    end
```

Everything works until this line

```
Scammer.requestors.where(requestor_ip: request.remote_ip).exists?
```

This lines causes this error

```
undefined method `requestors' for Scammer:Class
```

I've gone through Mongoid.org and various other posts here and on other boards, and I cannot find a way to access the embedded Requestor element off of Scammers. I am new to Ruby and trying to do the due diligence necessary to fix issues myself, but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer--there is nothing wrong with the models, it's the code block in the controller. Apparently once you return the object using the

```
where
```

you lose the ability to search or use other functions such as where, find and find_by.

I re-wrote the code block as such, and now it works

`if Scammer.where(email_used: search_term).exists?
          scammerRec = Scammer.find_by(email_used: search_term)`

```
      # Even though we found the parent object, we still need to use the .where function to pull the parent again and check for the requestor_ip in the requestors embedded doc
      if not Scammer.where(email_used: search_term, "requestors.requestor_ip" => request.remote_ip).exists?
        scammerRec.requestors.create(:requestor_ip => request.remote_ip)
      end 
      returnjson = Scammer.where(email_used: search_term).to_json
    else 
      # No entry found. We should now add this to the database as a search
      newscammer = Scammer.new(email_used: search_term, checked: 1, first_logged: DateTime.current(), status: "Seems Legit")
      requestor = Requestor.new
      requestor.requestor_ip = request.remote_ip
      Scammer.collection.update(newscammer.selector, {'$push' => {requestors: requestor.as_document}}, multi: true)
      newscammer.save
      returnjson = "{ 'message' : 'Email added to database' }"
    end
```